# FreeBSD - tcpdump - filtration of certain udp port

Tags: unix, udp, freebsd, tcpdump, packet-capture

I'm using freebsd 10.4
what argument i can use in tcpdump to match only certain UDP port?

is it -i parameter ?

this is what i already reviewed https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tcpdump(1)#end

Comment: No. The `-i` parameter is the interface you are monitoring traffic over. The expression `udp port 123` will show only UDP packets with a source or destination port of 123. See [pcap-filter(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pcap-filter&apropos=0&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD+12.1-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html).

Comment: doesnt seem to be working, Term] tcpdump tcp port 8443 -s0 -i nic0 -W 100 -C 100 -w "/tmp/any.cap" & [1] 69801 Term] tcpdump: syntax error –

Comment: I don't know why, it works for me.

Comment: Questions about the FreeBSD operating system and its utilities are off topic here and should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ Please delete this and ask over there. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

The option `-i` is for the interface from the [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tcpdump(1)):

```
-i interface
--interface=interface
          Listen on interface.  If unspecified, tcpdump searches the  sys-
          tem interface list for the lowest numbered, configured up inter-
          face (excluding loopback), which may turn out to be,  for  exam-
          ple, ``eth0''.
```

In the same man page you have some examples like:

```
To print all IPv4 HTTP packets to and from port 80,  i.e.  print  only
packets that  contain  data, not, for example, SYN and FIN packets and
ACK-only packets.  (IPv6    is left as an exercise for the reader.)

tcpdump 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) -   ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)'
```

Probably it is not the simplest one but can give you an idea to achieve what you are looking for.

Let's say you want to capture DNS request, `UDP` port `53` on your main interface `em0`, this could be a starting point:

```
tcpdump -i em0 'udp port 53'
```

Now if you want to go further you could use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) over `ssh`, give a try to:

```
wireshark -k -i <(ssh user@host sudo tcpdump -i em0 -U -w - not tcp port 22)
```

or in another way (in this case using PF interface [pflog](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pflog)):

```
ssh use@server sudo tcpdump -i pflog0 -U -w -| wireshark -k -i -
```